# Android: can you check if an app installation is fresh or there was already an older version of the app installed?

Tags: java, android

So I was wondering if you can check when installing an app in Android, if this installation is fresh (meaning that there is currently no older version of the app installed on the device) or it's not fresh (meaning that there is currently an older version of the app installed on the device and this is just an updated version).

I want to do something, but only if the installation is fresh and there is no older versions installed on the device. If there is such older version installed -> nothing should be executed. Was looking for something like `SystemUtils` and stuff, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Look to see if you have any data when your app runs. If you have data, a previous version of your app was installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution,jack a hack around for your problem.
1.Create a local database in your app ,that store the version number and date 
2.Calculate these two fields at time of startup of app or on your first activity start
3.if version number is same as your already exisiting last entry in db,then just overwrite the date with the new date;
4.So now when you update the app, you can check this version number with your current version number,if it doesnt match and is newer then you can know its new version

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code which checks if you have installed a newer version of an app:

```
private boolean showHelpOnFirstLaunch() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
        int currentVersion = info.versionCode;
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int lastVersion = prefs.getInt(PreferencesActivity.KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN, 0);
        if (currentVersion > lastVersion) {
            //save the current version in order to compare it the next time a newer version is installed
            prefs.edit().putInt(PreferencesActivity.KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN, currentVersion).commit();
            /* do what you want here */
            return true;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

`PreferencesActivity` is an activity of my project, but it is a static reference which resolves to: `public static final String KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN = "preferences_help_version_shown";`

What you ask is much simpler, you could just check if there exists a `lastVersion>0`. If not this means that it is the first ever installation of the app on the device